# Getting vim to be silent when using -s {scriptin}

Tags: vim

The vim man page describes `-s {scriptin}` option which allows for automation of file edits.  This works fine, but I'd like for vim not to grab the console in this case (and flash the file with edits), but to rather do its stuff silently and invisibly ... similar to a `vim -e -s` invocation.

Actually, my real need is to automate a file edit with vim in a silent way, so I guess use of `vim -e` would suffice if it weren't for the fact that I'm not familiar with ex mode (at least not when it comes to bread-and-butter editing commands), and creation of a `{scriptin}-format` file is just so easy (`vim -W`).  So ... I guess a `{scriptin}-format-to-ex-command-format` converter would be just as good.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is there any reason you couldn't use `sed`? This is what `sed` was designed for, and it uses standard regexp string replacement.

Here's an intro to `sed`: http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html

Comment: Actually, yes, very familiar with sed, and this is how I've done things in the past. Just like the idea of editing a file _in place_ without creating temp files/copying/cleaning up.

Comment: If you're using GNU sed you can use `sed -i` to edit files in place. I do it all the time.

Comment: Ok, now we're talking - thank you, I wasn't aware of that.

Comment: There is also `ed`, which is how you edit files in place when you need to be portable.